# Undefined reference to various functions while using opencv

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, tesseract, building

I am using OpenCV 2.4.10 with eclipse C++ with MinGW. This version of opencv only has libraries for visual C so I linked those libraries in MinGW (eclipse). I tried running a simple code for loading and displaying an image:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(){
  Mat image = imread("D:/photo1.tif",1);
  namedWindow( "Display", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display", image );
return 0;
}
```

But while building it shows following errors:

```
undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
```

I also tried the same with Tesseract OCR engine but there also it was showing the same problem i.e. undefined reference to various functions and classes. I don't know whether I am missing something in linking or building the files. So please help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

IMO Ashot's answer is almost correct, but I have a feeling you didn't build them at all. If that is the case..

[Build for MinGW](http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/), the libraries have different links to all the code and you can't compile with different compiled libraries

Answer (score 0):

How did you build your code? If the compiler is GCC then you need to add opencv libs with -l flag.

You can find opencv libs with the command - pkg-config opencv --libs (in Linux).

Comment: I am using G++ compiler and building the code in eclipse. 
Where can i find opencv mingw libraries in windows??

Answer (score 0):

"This version of opencv only has libraries for visual C so I linked those libraries in MinGW (eclipse)."

no, this will not work.

you can't use the prebuild visual studio ones, those are for a different compiler.

you will have to get cmake and **build** the opencv libs with mingw first.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by first buiding the libraries with CMake and then using it in eclipse.